# How to trigger an SMS in an specific time in app inventor 2?

Tags: app-inventor

For learning purposes,  I'm developing an app in app inventor 2 which should send to myself an SMS message with a list of bills with due date equals the current day -1. In other words, if the bill due date is tomorrow, it should send me an SMS today.
I already got the list of bills from tinyDB and I tried use clock.timer() to trigger the SMS. But the problem is when the clock triggers the SMS it sends a lot of messages and do not stop. I want it be sent only one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the SMS when the app is closed, you will need to look into [app inventor services](https://ai2gsoc16.wordpress.com/app-inventor-services/).

> ...which should send to myself an SMS message with a list of bills with due date equals the current day -1.

It would help if you provide a screenshot of your relevant blocks, but shouldn't it be the current day +1? The current day -1 would be yesterday. That would explain why you keep getting the message and it doesn't stop.